# develop a server based games across platforms including iphone, android, WP7

Tags: android, ios

programming is my hobby and I am not ready to leave my other profession yet. I have developed few windows applications, mostly on VB, some small scripts in python, C++, and so...never touched java or objective C

Now, I have few game, app ideas and I am sure they don't exist in iphone and android yet, and even browser based. Now , I want to develop those games in 5-6 months of time and I want users to be able to play from any platform, browser based, android, iphone, etc. just say like Zyanga poker.

I can pretty much give the details of games and even come up with some algorithms and /or idea in most states. So, how much it will cost to develop such program? Should I learn and do programming myself? or should I use unity like program for cross-platform deployment? what about looking for some investors or giving share to programmers, if so, where can I find such possibilities?

Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

> *how much it will cost to develop such program?*

Cost? money or time? Estimating game project (or all software project) scope is much harder than you think especially when you don't have enough experiences on developing similar types of games. 5-6 months of time could be more than enough to make one simple game but it really depends on the game you want to make and your skill. You think you can give the details of games for implementation but you will soon realize you need much more details to finish the job. Because it's your first time to make a video game, my advice here is that "**forget scope, start making the game and see how it goes**". It might sound silly first but you will be able to estimate cost more accurately as you build the game.

> *Should I learn and do programming myself? or should I use unity like
>   program for cross-platform
>   deployment?*

You probably should learn and program by yourself. Even if you decide to use a game engine like Unity, you still need to do programming with the engine. Also, a game engine can save you a great amount of coding but you should spend sometime learning the engine itself. Unity seems a solid choice and please go check its documents, forum and tutorials.

> *what about looking for some investors or giving share to programmers, if so,
>   where can I find such possibilities?*

This is more like a business question. You can ask this question here : http://answers.onstartups.com/
Before you search for investors or publishers, you better have a **playable** game demo. Game design documents do NOT work for getting a publisher unless you have successful commercial games you made before. Good Luck! :)

Comment: Thanks for very detailed answer,   I am afraid that doing it myself will result in a crapware because of the time and dedication I can give for game. and as you said getting investors is not easy just with concepts. So, I guess my best will be to find an investor who I already know and trusts me or go by myself how much I can go. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Whether it be IOS, Android, or WP7, they all want to lock you to work with the tools they support directly. IOS has arguably been the most strict, but that seems to change with the direction of the wind. There are some cross-platform development tools, but most of them are fairly expensive. IMO if you want it to be truly cross-platform, and isn't very graphics intensive, your best bet is probably HTML5 and Javascript. There are new Javascript libraries coming out every day it seems to help with gamedev, and while the support in different current generation browsers can be hit or miss, IE9, Chrome FF4, and most of the new mobile browsers have enough support for Canvas and other extensions to make it a credible platform.

YMMV